# Can Dell's New Workstation 3660 run two GPUs?

Tags: graphics

I am looking to buy new Dell workstation 3660 with i-7, 12700 CPU.
I would like to run a minimun of 8 Monitors.
This workstation has only following slots:

```
One PCIe x16 Gen5
One PCIe x4 Gen4
One PCIe x4 Gen3
```

When configuring on their website it allows me to install Two Nvidia T1000 GPUs & each has 4 miniDP ports so two will run 8 monitors.

[Dell Workstation 3660](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/workstations-isv-certified/new-precision-3660-tower-workstation/spd/precision-3660-workstation/xctopt3660us_vp?configurationid=57bf10ee-c73d-4ab8-b507-29b0fbaf0ac8)

But i-7 cpu supports only 20 PCIe lanes & each T1000 GPU requires 16 lanes.
So how Dell will put two GPUs & will they drive eight 24" monitors ( 1920x1200 ) ?
There is one open end x4 slot so will they put it there & if yes what about only 20 PCIe lanes for two GPUs ?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Dell offers two
[NVIDIA T1000](https://www.pny.com/nvidia-t1000)
cards, this is likely a bug in their website.

The T1000 is noted as using "PCI Express 3.0 x16",
while the Precision 3660 has only one such slot.

If you order this design, there is a good chance that the order will
be refused. Even worse, if they tried any doubtful solution to fit
the T1000 on top of an x4 slot, it will likely not support your
number of monitors, even if it somehow works.

I suggest choosing another computer model.
This one will not support your wanted configuration.

Comment: "If Dell offers two NVIDIA T1000 cards, this is likely a bug in their website"

Comment: "If Dell offers two NVIDIA T1000 cards, this is likely a bug in their website" Not just that, they also offer two AMD Radeon Pro WX3200 cards on FOUR different websites in FOUR different countries. ( There certainly will be more but I checked four countrie"s Dell websites ). So could there be a bug on all websites ? Also can you clarify when you say "it will likely not support your number of monitors, even if it somehow works" ? Thank You.

Comment: I have no hard information about it, but I doubt that the T1000 forced into an x4 slot will have the same performance as on x16 or will support 4 monitors (if it can be fitted).

Comment: From their maintenance manual it looks like they have one 4x slot open end & that is where they might fit the second T-1000 card. Is this something routine ?

Comment: I quote from [What is a PCIe Riser](https://linuxhint.com/pcie-riser/) : "As this type of riser only connects to a x1 or a x4 PCIe slot, it cannot deliver higher bandwidth than the riser cable. **This is ideal for workloads that are not bandwidth-demanding** but needs the efficiency of multiple GPUs. This is most commonly used in cryptocurrency mining rigs." The bandwidth of 4 terminals might be too much for x4.

Comment: Do cards share bandwidth ? What I mean is if one card is 16X & other 4X, will 16X card give some of it's bandwidth to 4X so it can run smoothly ? Thanks

Comment: No, connections are by lanes, x4 has 4 lanes and x16 has 16. See for example [Guide to PCIe Lanes](https://www.cgdirector.com/guide-to-pcie-lanes/).

Comment: harrymc, you sure have been very helpful. I need some more clarification. This Dell 3660 uses Intel W680 chipset & that chipset has maximum of 28 PCIe lanes. What are they for & could the be used to by PCIe slots to mount GPUs ? ?

Comment: They can, under certain conditions, but you need PCIe slots for them, and I don't know how many of these 28 lanes are already allocated.

Comment: Very Kind of you taking time to answer my questions. And yes, you have the ✔ check mark from me. Thank You.